# Accessing task initiated by different processes [ AMQP vs RPC backends ]

Tags: celery

I've been working working with Celery and AMQP storage back-end. I didn't like that it creates a new queue for every task/response and I found the new RPC result backend, which works as I would expect it to work.

However, this http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/whatsnew-3.1.html#new-rpc-result-backend when describing RPC backend says:

> New RPC result backend
>   This new experimental version of the amqp result backend is a good alternative to use in classical RPC scenarios, **where the process that initiates the task is always the process to retrieve the result.**

What does this mean? Does celery support processes accessing tasks initiated by different processes? That sounds interesting, any tips on how I could implement this?

Thanks a lot,

Answer (score 0):

In short, yes, you can access task initiated by another processes - you just have to somehow access tasks unique task_id.

More on it here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/celery-users/ECoFBCCCMHw